# How to redirect to home page after login using reactive WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I would like to programmatically login to a web application using reactive web client . I could see I am authenticated correctly but could not able to reach redirected url.

I access my application http://localhost:8080/myapplogin

Here my web client response will have a Location header http://localhost:8082/portal/auth/home , and I would like the browser to redirect to this url

I could see the application in 8082 authenticating and redirecting(/auth/home) but do not know how to make my web client return the response and do the redirection through browser. Can someone help

```
@GetMapping("/myapplogin")
Publisher<ClientResponse> mylogin() {
    
    MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("username", "testuser");
    formData.add("password", "test password");

    return WebClient.create()
            .post()
            .uri("http://localhost:8082/portal/auth/login")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
            .exchange();            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return status codes that start with 3, and a Location header holding the URL to redirect to.

```
@GetMapping("/myapplogin")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> mylogin() {
    return login()
            .map(res -> ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT)
                    .location(URI.create("/auth/home"))
                    .build()
            );
}
```

where `login` is

```
Mono<ClientResponse> login() {
    
    MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("username", "testuser");
    formData.add("password", "test password");

    return WebClient.create()
            .post()
            .uri("http://localhost:8082/portal/auth/login")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
            .exchange();            
}
```